# MySQL: Joined table columns without a certain column value

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores file information called `files`. Each row in the `files` table can be related to multiple **categories** and **tags**.

I have created a table called `file_relationships` that stores the link between the file and its categories and tags.

Basically what I want to do is filter my results based on certain categories and tags.

So for example I might want to extract all files with the tag number **12** and **15** and files with category number **1** and **2**.

However, let's say one of the files had the tag number **12** assigned to it but did not have any category relationships. I'd still want it to be included in the results.

I also want files without any tags and categories assigned to be included. I've acheived this by using `fr.relationship IS NULL` in my SQLFiddle link below.

I've created a quick mock up of the MySQL code I have been playing with. It's really bad code but hopefully it helps make sense of what I'm trying to achieve.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/931f2/1

Comment: Could it be you simply need to put an OR instead of the AND ?
See this SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/931f2/9

Comment: @ibizaman Very close but it will not give me the result I'm after. If a file has tag number **12** and category number **3** (3 not being searched for), I wouldn't want it to show. But if the file had tag number **12** and no category, then I'd want it to show. Am I making sense? Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have what you are looking for but let me obviously explain what is happening.  I am pre-querying (alias PQ) only from the file relationships table an aggregate on each file ID.  These aggregates are basically flags of 1 or 0 stating it does or not have something.

The result of the left-join, you want the entry if there are no relationships at all, so your IS NULL is obviously good to go.

Now, your consideration for a file that does not have ANY "TAG" or "CAT" entries.  This is where the MAX( IF()) for HasOtherRelation comes in.  Through all the entries for a given file ID, all I care about is "are there ANY entries other than cat or tag"... if so, set to 1, otherwise leave 0.  Similarly a flag for "HasTagOrCat", so in my where clause I am looking for anything that has an other relation = 1 AND the Has Tag Or Cat flag is zero.

Finally, on to your requirements of meeting your consideration for tag or cat qualifiers but not if the file has other cat or tag entries.  Similar MAX( IF()) for those.

```
select
      f.id,
      f.file_title
   from
      files f
         LEFT JOIN
         ( select 
                 fr.file_id,
                 max( if( fr.relationship IN ('tag','cat'), 1, 0 )) as HasTagOrCat,
                 max( if( fr.relationship NOT IN ('tag','cat'), 1, 0 )) as HasOtherRelation,
                 max( if( fr.relationship = 'tag' AND fr.relationship_id IN('12','15'), 1, 0 )) as HasTags,
                 max( if( fr.relationship = 'cat' AND fr.relationship_id IN('1','2'), 1, 0 )) as HasCats,
                 max( if( fr.relationship = 'tag' AND fr.relationship_id NOT IN('12','15'), 1, 0 )) as HasOtherTags,
                 max( if( fr.relationship = 'cat' AND fr.relationship_id NOT IN('1','2'), 1, 0 )) as HasOtherCats
              from 
                 file_relationships AS fr
              group by
                 fr.file_id ) PQ
         ON f.id = PQ.file_id
   where
         PQ.file_id IS NULL
      OR (    PQ.HasOtherRelation = 1
          AND PQ.HasTagOrCat = 0 )
      OR (    PQ.HasTags + PQ.HasCats > 0
          AND PQ.HasOtherTags + PQ.HasOtherCats = 0 )
```

So, at the end of the inner pre-query, your results would have the following

```
File_ID  HasTagOrCat  HasOtherRelation  HasTags  HasCats  HasOtherTags  HasOtherCats
1        1            0                 1        1        0             0
2        1            0                 1        1        1             1
3        1            0                 1        0        0             0
```

So, your data didn't have any such non tag/cat considerations in the data sample, nor any NULL for no such file entry in relationship table, but the others as summarized above would result in only file 1 & 3 being included in the result set...

They each have AT LEAST a Tag or Cat you were looking for an NO OTHER tag/cat that you did NOT want.  For entry 2, yes, it had both a tag and cat you were looking for, but ALSO had other tag/cats that you didnt so that is excluded from result.

Comment: I think that's perfect! I'll run some tests to ensure it's working as expected. Thank you so much for putting time into this for me :)

Answer (score 0):

replace and with or 
--->

(**fr.relationship = 'tag'** AND fr.relationship_id IN('12','15'))
**and** (**fr.relationship = 'cat'** AND fr.relationship_id IN('1', '2'))

you are checking if fr.relationship = 'tag' and  fr.relationship = 'cat' 
fr.relationship can be 'cat' or fr.relationship can be 'tag' for 1 record/row 
can't equal to both values

```
SELECT f.id,
       f.file_title ,fr.relationship
FROM files AS f
LEFT JOIN file_relationships AS fr
  ON f.id = fr.file_id
and /*REPLACEMENT as u want null column also */ (
  fr.relationship IS NULL
  OR (fr.relationship NOT IN ('tag','cat'))
  OR (
    (fr.relationship = 'tag' AND fr.relationship_id IN('12','15'))
    or (fr.relationship = 'cat' AND fr.relationship_id IN('1', '2'))
  )
)
GROUP BY f.id
EDIT---
```

IS THIS WHAT U WANT 
   http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/df016d/4

```
SELECT f.id,
       f.file_title ,group_concat(fr.relationship)
FROM files AS f
LEFT JOIN file_relationships AS fr
  ON f.id = fr.file_id
and  (
  fr.relationship IS NULL
  OR (fr.relationship NOT IN ('tag','cat'))
  OR (
    (fr.relationship = 'tag' AND fr.relationship_id IN('12','15'))
    or (fr.relationship = 'cat' AND fr.relationship_id IN('1', '2'))
  )
)
GROUP BY f.id
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Very close but it will not give me the result I'm after. If a file has tag number **12** and category number **3** (3 not being searched for), I wouldn't want it to show. But if the file had tag number **12** and no category, then I'd want it to show. Am I making sense? Really appreciate your help!